# How to get/read the wal2json output on a Java application/service , basically Parsing the json output from the wal2json plugin?

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch, replication, debezium

wal2json is an output plugin to get the logical decoding of postgres but , wal2json plugin outputs the changes on the terminal. How do I create a Java Listener or get the output on a Java application

Answer (score 0):

It is not done in Java, but here are two example projects to get an idea:

- node based: https://github.com/pdiniz13/node-wal2json
- golang based: https://github.com/jackc/pgx